# What is correct way to write language used?

Tags: prepositions

Do you say: "The following text is German" or " The following text is in German"

Comment: Both would probably be understood (in this particular context), but "in German" makes it obvious you're talking about the language, rather than a location of origin. "This book is German" would be taken to mean "This book is from Germany", not necessarily "This book is written in German".

Comment: Hi, dikotron, just dropping in as part of the community review. While (almost) totally answerable in its current state, we usually encourage Questioners to provide their own guesses. Meanwhile, I've upvoted SteveES's comment and hope it helps to answer your question. Thanks for your question and welcome to the English Language Learners Stack Exchange!

Comment: In addition to Teacher KSHuang's comment, you should also include [more context](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like the meaning that you are trying to express.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to say in what language something is written or spoken is to use the **"in"** preposition.

- The following text is **in** German
- The book is written **in** French
- The movie is **in** English
- The article is partly written **in** Chinese and partly **in** English

However, your first variant is also possible, but could confuse.

- This book is German - Does it come from Germany? Is it written in German? Does it look like a German book?
- This movie is French - Was it produced in France? Is the language used in the movie French?

This is likely to be understood as **"This is a German book"** which possibly but not 100% true can be either from Germany or written in German.